# Kotlin Language Development Wishlist Website

Tags: kotlin

I've been developing with Kotlin for a few months and I have several apps on Google Play. I have a fundamental and critical change I want to get to the Kotlin language development team for consideration. I'm sure this change also requires the language administration involvement as it also goes to the core of user experience with Android phones.

In addition, I have been building a 'Wishlist' or request for changes in how coding is applied in development.

I am usually successful in web searches, but in this case I can't find how to contact Kotlin resources. Am I going to wrong places? Is it in GitHub?

Comment: Issue tracker for Kotlin language is here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: I would start with [the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT). If your proposal is as far-reaching as you say, they may end up moving the discussion to a mailing list or some other communication method, but the issue tracker is a good starting point.

Comment: There is also the `language-evolution` channel on the Kotlin Slack workspace. https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up

Comment: Slack like Stack! Very helpful with evo comment, thanks! Surveys usually don't ask for comments, but will try.

Comment: Thanks VERY much, I would have preferred the use of the @myName or maybe I can't find where SO notified me of these critical comments.